# Count record in bulk insert

Tags: trigger

I have a problem that is, I want to count contact record which is related to account. I wrote this code. This code working fine. But when i have inserted via data loader bulk insert that time is not working.

```
trigger RestrictContactByName on Contact (after insert,after delete) {

set<Id> contactSet = new set<Id>(); 

for(Contact con : trigger.New){
if(con.AccountId != null){
contactSet.add(con.AccountId);
}
}

List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();

for(Account newAccount : [SELECT Id, NumberofLocations__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN : contactSet]){

newAccount.NumberofLocations__c = newAccount.NumberofLocations__c + 1;
accountList.add(newAccount);

}
Update accountList;
}
```

Comment: There are much simpler (and more complete) ways to manage rollups. Take a look at [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Comment: when you say 'not working' - what error do you get?

Comment: Do you want to have the total number of contacts per account expose in a field for each account? is that what you want?

Comment: Yes viasur. above coding is working fine. when i have created contact, corresponding account record get count

Comment: for example if i have a account record means, after that i have created contact record for that account record.  after that the field 'NumberofLocations__c' get increased to 1.

Comment: But What my problem is when i insert bulk records for contact through dataloader or anything else, that time account record field 'NumberofLocations__c' didn't get increased. Its working only for single record.

Answer (score 0):

If i Understood well you want to increase the NumberofLocations__c as a new contact is created, you can do this changing the code as follow...

I dont understand why you created the trigger for the delete event... anyway...

```
trigger RestrictContactByName on Contact (after insert,after delete) {
     if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
       Map<id,integer> accountsToChange = new Map<id,integer>(); 
       for(Contact con : trigger.New){
          if(accountsToChange.get(con.accountID) == null )
            accountsToChange.put(con.AccountID,0);
          accountsToChange.put(con.AccountID,accountsToChange.get(con.accountID)+1);

       }
       set<id> accountsId = accountsToChange.keyset();
       List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();

       for(Account newAccount : [SELECT Id, NumberofLocations__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN : accountsId]){
         newAccount.NumberofLocations__c = newAccount.NumberofLocations__c + accountsToChange.get(newAccount.id);
       }
       Update accountList;
     }
}
```

to understand better the triggers read this article

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

This should work, i didn't considered the after delete event, you can add it to the context in the if

```
if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
```